# Can I change mouse bindings in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, mouse-buttons

Xcode, thankfully, lets me change almost all key bindings via its Preferences. However, I want to also unleash the power of my mouse's many buttons. **Is there any way to change Xcode's mouse bindings?**

Answer (score 0):

Might depend on which mouse...

I use [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) with a Logitech MX518.
Lets you choose from an assortment of functions for each button/wheel etc.
Can define different functions sets per App.

However, it will not work on a Magic Mouse or Magic trackpad.

[image]

Comment: Neat! I want a solution for any mouse, though; I might be switching out mice frequently in coming months.

Comment: Not sure that can happen - unless they all number their buttons identically, which is unlikely